# Compute md5sum for each line in a file

Tags: hashsum, gnu-parallel

Given a file like:

```
a
b
c
```

How do I get an output like:

```
a       0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
b       92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
c       4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33
```

in an efficient way? (Input is 80 GB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could just be a oneliner in perl:

```
head 80gb | perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -nlE'say"$_\t".md5_hex($_)'
a       0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
b       92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
c       4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33
d       8277e0910d750195b448797616e091ad
e       e1671797c52e15f763380b45e841ec32
f       8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7
g       b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d
h       2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91
i       865c0c0b4ab0e063e5caa3387c1a8741
j       363b122c528f54df4a0446b6bab05515
```

If you need to store the output and want a nice progress bar while chewing this huge chunk:

```
sudo apt install pv          #ubuntu/debian
sudo yum install pv          #redhat/fedora
pv 80gb | perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -nlE'say"$_\t".md5_hex($_)' | gzip -1 > 80gb-result.gz
```

Comment: Impressive. This is even faster: `pv my80gb-file | parallel --pipe -Sworker1,worker2,worker3,: --round --block 1m -q perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -nlE'say"$_\t".md5_hex($_)'`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Ole Tange's approach, here's an optimized solution (Python's part):

**`md5summer.py`** script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import hashlib

for r in sys.stdin:
    if r.strip():
        h = hashlib.md5()
        h.update(r.encode());
        print r, '\t', h.hexdigest()
```

---

Points of optimization:

- `hashlib` - using actual library instead of deprecated one
- `for r in sys.stdin:` - reading from generator-like object instead of list
- `if r.strip():` - check for empty record to avoid redundant `hashlib` methods invocations

---

Usage:

```
parallel --pipepart -a my80gb-file -S server1,server2 --block 1 /path_to/md5summer.py
```

Sample output:

```
a   0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
b   92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
c   4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33
d   8277e0910d750195b448797616e091ad
f   8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7
e   e1671797c52e15f763380b45e841ec32
g   b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d
h   2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91
i   865c0c0b4ab0e063e5caa3387c1a8741
j   363b122c528f54df4a0446b6bab05515
k   8ce4b16b22b58894aa86c421e8759df3
l   2db95e8e1a9267b7a1188556b2013b33
m   6f8f57715090da2632453988d9a1501b
n   7b8b965ad4bca0e41ab51de7b31363a1
p   83878c91171338902e0fe0fb97a8c47a
o   d95679752134a2d9eb61dbd7b91c4bcc
q   7694f4a66316e53c8cdd9d9954bd611d
r   4b43b0aee35624cd95b910189b3dc231
s   03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034
t   e358efa489f58062f10dd7316b65649e
u   7b774effe4a349c6dd82ad4f4f21d34c
v   9e3669d19b675bd57058fd4664205d2a
w   f1290186a5d0b1ceab27f4e77c0c5d68
x   9dd4e461268c8034f5c8564e155c67a6
y   415290769594460e2e485922904f345d
z   fbade9e36a3f36d3d676c1b808451dd7
...
```

Comment: It seems to fail on input: Asunción. `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: On my system this solution is 50% slower than my solution.

Comment: Actually is this equivalent to Ole's solution? This one appears to be generating the cumulative hash not hash per line

Comment: I get the same output, so I would say: yes.

Comment: @iruvar, what do meant with "the cumulative hash"? It'll generate a new hash object for each next record

Comment: @OleTange, "this solution is 50% slower than my solution" - It depends. What's your Python version and what was the file size? One of the optimization points is reading from `sys.stdin` directly. Your version `sys.stdin.readlines():` should not go faster cause it reads from list instead of generator-like object

Comment: Yep I must have been drinking, +1

Comment: I got output `a
        60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3` on the first line on this. Because `\n` newlines aren't removed.

Answer (score 2):

First make a single threaded program (`md5er`), that can generate the correct output given the input:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import hashlib

for r in sys.stdin:
  print r[:-1], '\t', hashlib.md5(r[:-1]).hexdigest()
```

Then use GNU Parallel to split the input into chunks that can be distributed to compute servers:

```
parallel --pipepart -a my80gb-file -Sworker1,worker2,worker3,: --block -10 md5er
```

Comment: Python's `md5` module is deprecated. Use the `hashlib` module instead